# Borrowed value does not live long enough when adding rustls::Stream to a vector

Tags: ssl, networking, https, rust

I want to create an `Vec` and add opened socket connection to it. When I run the code, I get `borrowed value does not live long enough`. I saw many Q&A on Stack Overflow for this error, but I couldn't figure it out how to solve it for `rustls::Streams`.

After creating array of `rustls::Stream` , I want to use another loop and send data with opened streams.

```
use rustls::{ClientConfig, ClientSession, Session, TLSError};
use std::env;
use std::fmt;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Instant;
use webpki;
use webpki_roots;

fn main() {
    let mut config = rustls::ClientConfig::new();
    config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
    let arc = std::sync::Arc::new(config);
    let mut connectors = Vec::new();

    let now = Instant::now();
    {
        for n in 1..=2 {
            let mut socket = std::net::TcpStream::connect("X.X.X.X:443").unwrap();
            let dns_name = webpki::DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str("X.com").unwrap();
            let mut client = rustls::ClientSession::new(&arc, dns_name);
            let mut stream = rustls::Stream::new(&mut client, &mut socket); // Create stream
            connectors.push(stream);
        }
    }
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed: {:?}", elapsed);

    //AND LATER I'M GONNA ITERATE THROUGH THE VECTOR AND USE IT TO SEND DATA.
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0597]: `client` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:50
   |
38 |             let mut stream = rustls::Stream::new(&mut client, &mut socket); // Create stream
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
39 |             let data_ref = &mut stream;
40 |             connectors.push(data_ref);
   |             ---------- borrow later used here
41 |         }
   |         - `client` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `socket` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:63
   |
38 |             let mut stream = rustls::Stream::new(&mut client, &mut socket); // Create stream
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
39 |             let data_ref = &mut stream;
40 |             connectors.push(data_ref);
   |             ---------- borrow later used here
41 |         }
   |         - `socket` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `stream` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:39:28
   |
39 |             let data_ref = &mut stream;
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
40 |             connectors.push(data_ref);
   |             ---------- borrow later used here
41 |         }
   |         - `stream` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: *I saw many Q&A on Stackoverflow for this error* — please **link** to the questions that you have already read and don't understand. Otherwise, a potential answerer risks wasting their time and yours by telling you the exact same thing that you've already read and don't understand.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions) are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: The example is not minimal. For example, you have imported `File`, which is not used. There are multiple others. You have not provided which versions of crates you are using. You haven't provided what version of Rust you are using, or what OS. I don't know if any of that is required to answer the question, but providing it is the best way to get a quick answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes it isn't used, but it worked before I try to add `rustls::Stream` to a `Vec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`StreamOwned`](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.17.0/rustls/struct.StreamOwned.html) instead:

```
use rustls::{ClientConfig, ClientSession, StreamOwned}; // 0.17.0
use std::{net::TcpStream, sync::Arc, time::Instant};
use webpki::DNSNameRef; // 0.21.2
use webpki_roots; // 0.19.0

fn main() {
    let mut config = ClientConfig::new();
    config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
    let arc = Arc::new(config);

    let now = Instant::now();
    let _connectors: Vec<_> = (0..2)
        .map(|_| {
            let socket = TcpStream::connect("X.X.X.X:443").unwrap();
            let dns_name = DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str("X.com").unwrap();
            let client = ClientSession::new(&arc, dns_name);
            StreamOwned::new(client, socket)
        })
        .collect();
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("Elapsed: {:?}", elapsed);
}
```